# Alter initial state in React Native with Redux

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm currently developing an app that has a signin and signup screen. When the user successfully signs in (or signs up), I navigate the user to the 'My Account' screen.

On both signin/signup screens I have a 'email' and 'password' `<TextInput>`. When the user types something on the email `<TextInput>`, I update the 'email' state variable. Same for 'password'.

Here's the initial state of my `loginReducer.js`:

```
const initialState = { 
    errorMessage: '', // signin/signup error message
    isLoading: false, 
    email: '',        // 'email' textinput on signin/signup screen
    password: '',     // 'password' textinput on signin/signup screen
    user: null,       // object with logged user, if logged of course
};
```

When the user navigates between the signin/signup screen, I reset the state so the textinputs are cleared!

Here's what I'm not sure whats the proper way to do:

The 'My Account' screen also has these same fields! Email and password, so the user can change his email or password if he so desires. The initial values of these fields in the 'My Account' screen is of course **his email and password**, while the initial values of these fields in the Signin/Signup screen is an **empty string**! Now, suppose the user starts changing his email (on the 'My Account' screen) and while typing he decides to go to the Home Screen for example. When he comes back, I want to 'reset' the state back to his **initial email**, and not an empty string.

That's what I mean by 'Alter Initial State'.. I kinda wanted to update the initialState when the user signs in.. somehow reuse this reducer, but as I'm new to React Native I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do.. What do you guys suggest? Should I create a new reducer just for the 'My Account' screen? Another approach perhaps?

Thank you, and apologies if duplicated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in the wrong way. Why passing user infos to redux ?

You'd do better to manage the signup/signin process in the local state and **THEN** dispatch necessary infos to redux like user and email.

This way you can check if the fields are ok (ex: password with 8 characters min), then send to backend, then dispatch.

Seems to me a better workflow

Comment: I agree it must be overkill to use redux in this case, but I plan on doing another app in which the signup screen might have multiple steps/screens, and I'll use this current app as a start point. I'm just doing this way for the sake of getting experience hehe. I'm just not sure how to set the initial state as the logged user email.